# Highcharts navigator not working with data set

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Can someone please take a look at this example? It works when I use a smaller data set, but when I use a larger historical data set, it stops working and the data series does not render. Please help.

Small data set example - http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/250/

Large data set example (SERIES DOES NOT RENDER) - http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/249

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        height: 120
    },
    navigator: {
        series: {
            data: chartData
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [null],
        markers: {
            enabled:true
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your data sorted in ascending time order. Currently your "large" data set is not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of problems. First of all, as said @wergeld, you need to sort your data:

```
chartData.sort(function(a,b) { return a[0] - b[0]; });
```

Then the problem is with setting option for navigator:

```
    navigator: {
        series: [{
            name: 'MSFT',
            data: chartData
        }]
    },
```

When should be an object, not an array:

```
    navigator: {
        series: {
            name: 'MSFT',
            data: chartData
        }
    },
```

And the last one, do you really need to set `xAxis.min/max` ? Escpecially to values 2 and 4. when you have timestamps like

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/253/

Comment: Pawel, the Jsfiddle doesnt work for me, is there something missing?

Comment: It works for me.. maybe you are referring to the almost empty navigator? It's caused by null point in the main series.